# risk to go from xcode 6 to xcode 7

Tags: xcode6, xcode7

I have a lot of problems with xcode 6 at the moment. For me it is nearly unusable.
- performance during building the code and also errorchecking, indexing ...
- autocomplition doesn't work sometimes.
- redirecting to functions works 20% of time (clicking on function or variable to redirect to code). Sometimes it works sometimes not.

I guess the problems went with growing of my apps code.

So I ask me if I should go for XCode 7, which promises a lot for solving my issues. Then I heard about migration problems too.

Are there any experienced developers which went from xcode6 to sxcode7 and do they suggest to do this ?

Comment: For me, Xcode 6 was very stable. Xcode 7 is giving me problems in source control menu, won't stop indexing, and puts in bad framework paths for unit tests.

Comment: Xcode 6 problems were mainly local or caused by a bad installation/upgrade. Xcode 7 has exactly the same problems. Removing all components & simulators and reinstalling (also removing derived data for all projects) usually fixes the problems. You might also want to upgrade your system and iTunes. The performance problems you are experiencing (autocompletion problems can be a symptom) could also be caused by a different app. I would recommend to close all big apps when working in Xcode, especially when more than 1 tab is open and simulator is running.

Comment: If you have a Swift 1.x codebase, upgrading is not an easy option, especially if your app is for Apple Watch. Then you will need both Xcode versions installed.

Answer (score 0):

Close Xcode. Rename the app "Xcode6". Install Xcode 7. Try it and see if it fixes your problems.